# Modal shell not working properly

Tags: java, shell, swt

I am using the following code:

```
Shell parent = getParent();
Shell dialogShell = new Shell(parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM |SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

When I minimize the application the child `dialogshell` also gets minimized. That is ok(expected behaviour), but while using tab the child dialog shell sometimes appears in front of some other application.

I want that child `dialogshell` to be tightly coupled with the application only and should not appear with some other application open in the browser.

Comment: How do you manage to minimize the application at all? Do you do that from code?

Comment: when i use tab to open other application my java application goes in background with dialogshell, but sometime for other application dialogshell aapears,,i want that dialogshell should aaper only java aap appears using alt+tab

Comment: Which OS are you using?